# a nice alternative in countdown timer - putting "0" in front of single digit

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've been building countdown timer and I was wondering if I can replace this code:

```
if( daysLeft< 10){
  daysLeft = "0" + daysLeft;
 }

 if( hoursLeft< 10){
  hoursLeft = "0" + hoursLeft;
 }

 if( minutesLeft< 10){
  minutesLeft = "0" + minutesLeft;
 }

 if( secondsLeft< 10){
  secondsLeft = "0" + secondsLeft;
 }
```

with something more appropriate (nicer). 
Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/U7R6W/6/
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creat a function to do this:

```
function addLeadingZero(i) {
    if(i < 10)
        return "0" + i;
    return i;
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
var x = 5;
var result = addLeadingZero(x);
```

Answer (score 3):

DRY things up :

```
function zeroPad(number)
{
  if (number < 10)
    return ("0" + number);
  return (number.toString());
}
```

Then use `zeroPad` wherever you need.

This method returns a String in each case for consistency.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless the argument of whether enhancing prototypes is bad or not, a valid solution would be:

```
Number.prototype.twoDigitString = function(){ 
                                     return this<10?"0"+this:""+this.toString();
                                  }
```

And then you could just do:

```
secondsLeft.twoDigitString();
minutesLeft.twoDigitString();
```

to get the formatted output.

Answer (score 1):

TRY

```
 String.prototype.leftPad = function() { 
            var final = (this.length>1) ? this : "0" + this; 
            return final.toString();
 }
"2".leftPad(); // return "02"
"22".leftPad(); // return "22"
```

Comment: should be `>=2` or `>1` ;)

Comment: Thanks Christoph , for the Tip. But I am confused why we need to change back with `.ToString()` whereas I have added this method to String prototype. any idea!!

Comment: Since you bound it to `String.prototype`, final does not contain the normal primitive string value you would get when doing `var final = "string"` but a real String *Object* like if you would do `var final = new String("string")`.

Comment: In real life context this should not matter, because `String.prototype.toString()` is automatically called when encountering a String context, however your webdeveloper console will prompt you the entire Object instead of a single string value. You might find the [MDN Docs about Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Distinction_between_string_primitives_and_String_objects) useful.